# The Logarithm of Subtraction of two variables

Tags: logarithms

What is the result of this expression , It should mention that the `log`
is natural logarithm.
$$
\log\left(\exp(-x) - \exp(-y)\right)
$$

Could we use the formula which mentioned in wikipedia about logarithmic identities?

$$
\log_{b}(a -c) = \log_b a + \log_b(1- \frac{c}{a})
$$

and does any body know the refrence of the above mentioned [formula in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Summation.2Fsubtraction)?

Comment: The formula works well, as $$\log(e^{-x} - e^{-y}) = \log\left(e^{-x}(1-e^{x-y})\right) = -x + \log(1-e^{x-y}).$$

Comment: @Pragabhava: Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are familiar with $$\log r+\log s=\log(rs)$$ Now if you replace $r$ with $a$, and $s$ with $1-(c/a)$, you get $$\log a+\log(1-(c/a))=\log(a(1-(c/a)))=\log(a-c)$$ So that's the source of the identity you quote.

Answer (score 0):

We can't really make it any simpler, sadly.

Also, notationally, we might write $e^{-x}$ or $\exp(-x)$, but not $\exp^{-x}$.

Comment: Means that there is no formula for logarithm  of subtraction?

Comment: Exactly. Neither for addition. 'What operation is before +?'